# Scroll management in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, scroll, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

In my WP8 app I'm trying to implement a functionality that will allow me to save `LongMultiListSelector`'s scroll position and scroll it to that position at a later time (after tombstoning for example). It proved to be quite a quest and despite some progress I still have questions.

As I understand it now I'll need the following things for this to work:

1. Obviously **an ability to scroll to a specified item** which I now have. (`LongMultiListSelector`, despite being an extension of `LongListSelector`, does not have `ScrollTo` method, although `LongListSelector` can be found in `LongMultiListSelector`'s visual tree and that is what I've done).

   1.1. **Ability To scroll to a specified item with animation** and this one I haven't solved yet. It is not that important but having it would be nice. After some searching I've found out that once `LongListSelector` had `AnimateTo` method but currently it has it not.
2. **Ability to find out what items of `LongListSelector` are currently visible on screen** so I can save index of one of these visible items and then scroll to it. This one I also have not solved yet and it is very important.

   After some searching I've found this question: [WP7 Toolkit Update Removed GetItemsInView() from the LongListSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124262/wp7-toolkit-update-removed-getitemsinview-from-the-longlistselector). Is says that in former times `LongListSelector` had a `GetItemsInView` function, at a later times it had `Link` and `Unlink` events especially for this purpose. Currently `LongListSelector` has neither of these options.

   So the main question is what should I do now to find visible items in `LongListSelector`?

Answer (score 4):

I looks like currently there's no easy and direct way at all to find which items are visible. Fortunately not everything is lost. Both `ScrollBar` and `LongListSelector` can be found in `LongListSelector`'s visual tree at runtime.

`LongListSelector` is needed for it's `ScrollTo` method and from `ScrollBar` I need a `ValueChanged` event where I can get `ScrollBar.Maximum` and `ScrollBar.Value` which are control height and current offset, respectively. The problem again is that these two properties are not always calculated correctly perhaps due to `LongListSelector`'s virtualization and the fact that it does not show all the items at once. Good thing is that negative distance (Maximum - Value, an offset from end of list) is, although relative, always right.

So if it's possible for you to manually calculate real height of your `LongListMultiSelector` then scroll management becomes possible using that real height and negative distance. In my case it was easy because all of the items are of the same height.

Comment: Anton do you have any code example of this online? A github gist or something? I'm interested in this manual calculation approach!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to **Ability To scroll to a specified item with animation**:

[This](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.ru/2013/04/smooth-scrolling-content-on-windows.html) article will help you.

**The main idea**: ScrollViewer's `VerticalOffset Property` is marked as read-only. So you can create a shell-class that will help you to animate VerticalOffset.